# Lost my Private key but ı have keystore

Tags: go-ethereum, myetherwallet, private-key, error, keystore

I have mew v2 json file. I want to convert this file to v3 utc via geth but I am getting an error, what should I do? i get the same error on windows 10 and linux (kali and ubuntu)

Geth Error:
Fatal: Failed to load the private key: key file too short, want 64 hex characters

Method i tried:
https://help.myetherwallet.com/en/articles/5449838-importing-a-v2-json-file

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on the initial direction of the question (convert to v3) however I did find this post on what seems to be a very similar issue with geth account import key file issue (from 2016).  I have seen this issue in other areas regarding key import / export where possible "0x" stripping occurs. Here is the link to the "Go Ethereum" GitHub question:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2503

To summarize for succinctness (and in the interest of disclosure and accreditation, here is a screenshot of the relevant comment)

[image: Tayvano user comment snapshot]

Comment: i tried but it opens new wallet

Comment: So, you are no longer experiencing the issue referenced in the post above? I must still be unclear on your issue? It looks like MAYBE you are talking about an encrypted wallet stored in a JSON file?  If that is your scenario, you need to re-ask the question properly or open a new question.  Good luck...